# fetch array php

Tags: php, arrays, fetch

I am working on fetching data from a table in PHP with the following code. How can I copy all rows directly into an array? I tried `fetch_array()` instead of `fetch()` but it was also not successful.

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($aID, $sID);

while ($stmt -> fetch()) { 
    echo $aID . " ". $sID . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I copy all rows directly into array?

- MySQLi - [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)
- PDO - [fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: Will that be like this? ` $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql); 
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($aID, $sID);
   $allrows = $stmt->mysqli_fetch_all();
   echo $allrows ->rowcount(); `

Comment: Assuming you are using MySQLi OOP, the method is just `fetch_all()`. Reference the links I provided to the PHP Docs. They are your friend.

Comment: I changed to this now but still not working. Any idea? `While ($row = $stmt -> fetch_all()){ echo $row[0]; echo $row[1];}`

Answer (score 1):

If using `PDO`

the `Fetch_column` is what you are looking for

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($aID, $sID);
    $Arrays = $stmt ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Comment: I tried like this but not echoing.  `            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql); 
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($aID, $sID);

   while ($row = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)){
    echo $row[0];
    echo $row[1]; 
   }`

Comment: First things first; are you using mysqli or PDO? and try my structure and `print_r($Arrays);` Does this return an array that you are looking for?

Comment: Oh..sorry .. I am using mysqli.

Comment: This should be mentioned in your question then; Dis-regard this post, it's for PDO

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: This answer would be improved with an explanation of what the code is doing/how it would solve the problem. It's currently being identified as a low quality post due to length and content